# How does one setup VC++ dynamic linking via command-line?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dynamic-linking, cl

Though I have no problem setting up run-time DLL loading via Visual Studio, I'm having some trouble when doing it manually through the Visual Studio CLI tools.

Say we have the following 2 simple C++ source files we'd like to compile, one for the binary executable and one for the DLL:

**main.cpp**

```
void say_hello();

int main()
{
    say_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

**say_hello.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void say_hello()
{
    printf("Hello DLL World!");
}
```

What are the steps to compile `say_hello.cpp` file as a DLL then dynamically link it with the call from `main.cpp`?

Based on my read through of the MSDN docs, I was able to successfully compile the `say_hello.dll` and application then run it and  using the following commands:

```
cl say_hello.cpp /LD
lib say_hello.obj
cl say_hello.lib main.cpp
```

Unfortunately, this seems to only allow for statically linking the application via the `say_hello.lib` file (which can be confirmed by deleting both the .lib and .dll file, which still lets the binary run successfully).

What commands/parameters do I have to pass to the compiling/linking phase to have `main.exe` use the DLL instead of a static library?

Comment: `cl say_hello.cpp /LD` should produce the DLL and an import library in .lib file. The subsequent `lib` command then overwrites the aforementioned import library with static library. Just don't do that. Another problem is that names need to be explicitly exported from a DLL, via a DEF file or `__declspec(dllexport)`. As written, you aren't exporting any, so there's nothing to actually link to.

Comment: Ahhh yes... the console output of that first step `cl say_hello.cpp /LD` does seem to indicate that a "/implib:say_hello.lib" did get created, but I only see the `say_hello.obj` and `say_hello.dll` generated in the directory.  Is there some other flag to pass to tell it not to cleanup the import library?

Comment: Ahh I see, the `__declspec(dllexport)` macro prefixing the function to be exported is critical, because without it cl.exe winds up deleting the import library file `say_hello.lib` immediately upon completion.

Comment: Yes, because there would be nothing to import ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. Not every thing is entirely necessary (DLLMain e.g.) but I think those are things you should look up ;-)

SayHello.cpp

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx : Decorated Names
extern "C" {  // somehow making it superfluous to put the code in SayHello.cPP ...but anyway ;-)
    // see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx : dllexport, dllimport
    __declspec(dllexport) void say_hello()
    {
        printf("Hello DLL World!");
    }

  // see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx : (optional) DllMain entry point
    BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
        )
    {
        switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllimport) void say_hello(); }  // we did this in SayHello.cpp, so we have to do it here too.
// otherwise the name wouldn't match

int main() {
    say_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

and then compiling/linking

```
cl /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL SayHello.cpp /LD /link /OUT:SayHello.dll
```

/LD tells the linker to build a DLL *and* to use /MT, see [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx). (via the OUT: parameter you *could* change the name of the .dll; here it's the default, just for demonstration purpose. If you leave it out, you can also skip the /link parameter since there would be no linker parameters anymore.)

```
cl.exe /MT main.cpp /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "SayHello.lib"
```

matching the run-time lib settings for the dll, creating a [console application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) (main.cpp has a `int main()`) and linking the stub lib of SayHello (instead of using [LoadLibrary("SayHello.dll")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[GetProcAddress(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Doh, jumbled up the compiler/linker parameters of the second cl.exe command. Note to self: first test, then post.

Answer (score 0):

I marked the answer by VolkerK as correct since it includes some other important Windows DLL API details that are definitely worth a read, but I wanted to summarize the *bare minimum* changes one could make it get the dynamic linking working in the most simple example based on Igor Tandetnik and VolkerK's comments.

- Adding the macro `__declspec(dllexport)` before at least one function to be exported in the DLL is essential, otherwise the library compiling command won't creating an import library to indicate which functions are available for dynamic linking.
- The second "lib say_hello.obj" was totally wrong, as the DLL compiling command will correctly make the say_hello.lib (whereas that lib command would only generate a static library and wind up overwriting the first command).

Here's the full most basic working example:

**main.cpp**

```
void say_hello();

int main()
{
    say_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

**say_hello.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void say_hello()
{
    printf("Hello DLL World!");
}
```

**Compilation commands:**

```
cl say_hello.cpp /LD
cl main.cpp say_hello.lib
```